# Rails ActionCable & Partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

### Action Cable is configured to correctly to subscribe, broadcast, etc.

However, I'm getting the behavior of user `avatars` rendering on the wrong side due to a `Rails partial`.

```
# conversations/_message.html.erb

<% if current_user.id == message.user_id %> 
  <Display Avatar Right>
  </Display Avatar Right>
<% else %>
  <Display Avatar Left>
  </Display Avatar Left>
<% end %>
```

When a message belongs to the current user, the avatar needs to be **on the right**, when not, the avatar needs to be **on the left**.

In the `create_message` method of my `MessagesChannel`, this is the method that is called when a user creates a new message. The issue is, when a message is created, `current_user` is the user who created the message. This will render the correct HTML for **This user ALONE**. **Other users/subscribers** to the channel will be broadcasted the SAME HTML... this will result in the bug seen in the first screen shot.

```
def create_message(message_params)
  message = Message.new context_type: 'Conversation'
  message[:body] = message_params['data']['body']
  message[:context_id] = message_params['data']['conversation_id']
  message[:user_id] = message_params['data']['user_id']
  data = {}
  if message.save
    data[:html] = ApplicationController.render partial: 'conversations/message', locals: { message: message, current_user: current_user }
  else
    p message.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    data[:html] = "Error: #{message.errors.full_messages.to_sentence}"
  end

  ActionCable.server.broadcast('room', data)
end
```

## The bug is, in

```
# conversations/_message.html.erb
```

`if current_user.id == message.user_id` will always return true and the avatar displays on the right even for other users(users who are subscribed to this channel.)

Another thing is, I don't want to touch the behavior in the partial because for the user who **sent** the message, the html sent back from the `MessagesChannel` is correct(it renders the avatar on the right.)

## Here are two screenshots to illustrate

#### Incorrectly displays for other subscribers screen.

[image]

#### Correctly displays for message sender screen.

[image]

Anyone know a workaround where I can still use this `_message` partial? Thanks!

Comment: You might need to add the related model and controller code too.

Comment: I could but I know that's not the issue. The issue is this, when the html is rendered in `MessagesChannel` action, current_user will always be the user who created the message, thus when the partial is rendered with `ApplicationController.render ...` the partial always branches the same way.

I thought about adding model code but it's sorta complicated. `Message` belongs to a `Conversation`. `Conversation` can have many `Users`, through `UserConversations`.

Answer (score 1):

hej,
your partial is being rendered before being broadcasted. the broadcast_to method transmits a string which is the rendered html of the partial. as a result, when you render your partial, the current_user is the one who sends the message and therefore it is rendered the way the sender sees the partial.
a solution could be to pass a boolean variable "sender" to your partial, i.e.

```html
<% if sender %> 
  <Display Avatar Right>
  </Display Avatar Right>
<% else %>
  <Display Avatar Left>
  </Display Avatar Left>
<% end %>
```

then you transmit both the sender and the receiver partials in the data object and the sender Id, e.g.

```
data[:htmlSender] = ApplicationController.render partial: 'conversations/message', locals: { message: message, sender: true }
```

data[:htmlReceiver] = ApplicationController.render partial: 'conversations/message', locals: { message: message, sender: false, }
data[:senderId] = current_user.id.to_s

then you make a conditional in the received(data) callback where you compare the senderId from your data Object with the current_user id and insert either data.htmlSender or data.htmlReceiver.

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful for a similar problem I have.  What I can't figure out is, where do I get the "current_user" id from within the received(data) function in the channel javascript?  If I can figure out how to get that, then I know how to do the logic to compare things as you suggest.  But I feel like I'm missing something in there.  How does the received() function know who the current_user is?

Answer (score 0):

You have typed `<% if current_user.id = message.user_id %>`.

Replace `=` with `==`.

`=` will return the value of `message.user_id` which is truth in your case.

Comment: That was a typo in my question, my bad. It is correctly typed in the `_message.html.erb` partial. `if current_user.id == message.user_id`

Answer (score 0):

`current_user.id = message.user_id` this is an assignment. The control flow will always go into if block. Using `==` should be right.